# Cordova hybrid mobile app getting SecurityError connecting to O365

Tags: office365, visual-studio-cordova, sharepoint-online

My Cordova app is getting the following error when running on my Android device:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Refused to connect to 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.

However, when I run the app inside VS 2015 Ripple emulator it works exactly as expected. Is there something I need to add to the Content Security Policy to allow authentication to take place on my device?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known issue, Cordova ver. 5 has released new security principles (CSP) that you need to configure/adjust to allow remote connections to any api endpoint.

Update the CSP meta tag to allow XHR requests to external urls using https protocol as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https:">
```

Comment: don't forget to add cordova whitelist plugin as well. read more about cordova 5 security requirements for Android devices.  https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist